# Product of nilpotent matrices is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A$ and $B$ be two nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices that commute (so $AB=BA$), how do I show that $AB$ is nilpotent as well?

I have frankly no idea how to start this proof, so excuse me for not showing what I have done so far.

Comment: Because they commute, $(AB)^n=A^nB^n$ (by induction). Now what?

Comment: Can you tell us what it means to be nilpotent?

Comment: @JohnHughes It means that there exists an $m$ s.t. $A^m=0$

Comment: You can simply travel forward in time and ask your future self who's already got answered here :)

Comment: @Kaster I can only travel in time to save my mom ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since A,B commute you know that $ (AB)^n = A^nB^n$
A is nilpotent, so there exists $ m \in \mathbb N$
such that $A^m=0$.
so $\:(AB)^m=0B^m=0$